# Foldl with lambda expresion

Tags: haskell, foldleft

Hi I'm trying to sum a list of tuples into a tuple with the foldl function,
I tryed it with using as parameter a lambda expresion but it's giving out a wrong value 
here the code:

```
data Point = Point {x,y :: Float}
sumPoint :: [Point] -> (Float,Float)
sumPoint xs = foldl (\(a,b) x-> (0+a,0+b)) (0.0,0.0) xs
```

It should come out `sumPoint [Point 2 4, Point 1 2, Point (-1) (-2)] = (2.0,4.0)`
But im getting `(0.0,0.0)`
How is this making any sense?

Comment: Well you're entirely ignoring `x` and `0+a` is the same as `a`, so you can see there's definitely no summation going on here. Try changing your lambda to something that adds two tuples.

Comment: Oh I see, so it should be something like this? `sumPoint xs = foldl (\(a,b) (x,y)-> (x+a,y+b)) (0.0,0.0) xs` but I'm getting a strange error, it expects  `[(Float, Float)]`  actual type  `[Point]`  but Point is a (Float,Float)

Comment: @Kevin Close. Try `(\(a,b) (Point x y)-> (x+a,y+b)) ` since the second argument is a point, not a pair.

Comment: @chi Thanks for the tip it works out, I thought since point is defined as a pair the pattern should match.

Comment: Haskell uses nominal typing (like most programming languages), where even if two types are defined in the same way but have a different name they are considered distinct types. Here, `Point` and `(Float,Float)` are structurally identical, but have a different name, so there is no automatic conversion.

Answer (score 3):

To be a little structural you better define operations among `Point` type values and then convert the `Point` type to Tuple wherever needed. Otherwise you may directly use Tuple and discard the `Point` type.

```
data Point = Point {x,y :: Float} deriving Show

toTuple :: Point -> (Float, Float)
toTuple p = (x p, y p)

addPts :: Point -> Point -> Point
addPts p q = Point (x p + x q) (y p + y q)

sumPts :: [Point] -> Point
sumPts = foldl addPts (Point 0 0)
```

So what you need is `toTuple . sumPts` function.

```
*Main> :t toTuple . sumPts
toTuple . sumPts :: [Point] -> (Float, Float)
```

Answer (score 2):

I changed it to

```
sumPoint xs = foldl (\(a,b) (Point x y)-> (x+a,y+b)) (0.0,0.0) xs
```

The problem was I was ignoring the x and at 0+a is nothing happening.